# Flash combobox - disappearing prompt

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm using the cs3 combobox control. I want the prompt "Select a City"to persist, but it disappears as soon as you select an item in the list. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks!

```
public class ComboSkin extends Sprite
{
    private var _cboCities:ComboBox = new ComboBox();

    public function ComboSkin()
    {
        init();
    }


    private function init():void
    {
        _cboCities.y = 30;
        _cboCities.setSize(100, 15); 
        _cboCities.prompt = "Select a City";

        var items:Array = [ 
            {label:"San Francisco", data:"601 Townsend St."}, 
            {label:"San Jose", data:"345 Park Ave."}, 
            {label:"San Diego", data:"10590 West Ocean Air Drive, Suite 100"}, 
            {label:"Santa Rosa", data:"2235 Mercury Way, Suite 105"}, 
            {label:"San Luis Obispo", data:"3220 South Higuera Street, Suite 311"} 
        ]; 
        _cboCities.dataProvider = new DataProvider(items);


        var tf:TextFormat;// = new TextFormat(); 

        tf = new TextFormat("Arial", 8, 0x000000);
        _cboCities.textField.height = 10;
        _cboCities.textField.setStyle("textFormat", tf);
        addChild(_cboCities);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Why are you extending Sprite? Why not extend ComboBox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After selecting the dropdown, just save the selectedItem in your own class, and reassign  the dataprovider to the component, it will overwrite all the data, and the prompt should come visible again.

> var selectedCity = null;
>
> _cboCities.y = 30;
>
> _cboCities.setSize(100, 30);
>
> _cboCities.prompt = "Select a City";
>
> ```
>     var items:Array = [ 
>         {label:"San Francisco", data:"601 Townsend St."}, 
>         {label:"San Jose", data:"345 Park Ave."}, 
>         {label:"San Diego", data:"10590 West Ocean Air Drive,Suite 100"}, 
>         {label:"Santa Rosa", data:"2235 Mercury Way, Suite 105"}, 
>         {label:"San Luis Obispo", data:"3220 South Higuera Street,Suite 311"} 
>     ]; 
>
>     _cboCities.dataProvider = new DataProvider(items);
>
>   _cboCities.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE, function():void{
>
>               selectedCity = items[_cboCities.selectedIndex].label;
>
>               trace(selectedCity)
>
>               _cboCities.dataProvider = new DataProvider(items);
>
>   })
> ```

Comment: Thanks. The thing is if I select "San Francisco" I want "San Francisco" to be shown as the selected item. But I want the "Select A City" prompt to be at the top of the dropdown when I open it.  I want "Select A City" to  be, in other words, a selectable item just like the others. Basically a different movie plays when each city is selected. If the user selects "Select A City" (or whatever string I want to put there) then no movie plays. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: OK sorry i was thinking in flex. I edit my code, it work fine in flash

Comment: I'll go ahead and accept this answer since it closely answers the question. What I ended up doing was to put a space before "Select A City" so that it always comes up first in an alphabetical sort.